# recognize mp4 file using Google Speech

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm using postman in order to execute POST method to google cloud speech api :

> https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=

```
{
"config": {
    "encoding": "FLAC",
    "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
    "languageCode": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
      "content":"AAAAHGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28ybXA0MQAAAAhmcmVlAACrdm1kYXQhEUUAFFABR..."}}
```

the audio file is mp4 format, and I used an online converter to get Base64 encode.

I'm getting empty response {}, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION : 
mp4 is not a FLAC encode, and not support by Google speech for now,
I convert it to Flac, encode to Base64String and it works.
:)

Comment: How did you convert the mp4 into FLAC?